# Почему последний alert даёт false?

Tags: javascript, ооп

```
function Animal(name) {
this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.getName = function () {
return this.name;
};

function Dog(name) {
Animal.apply(this, arguments);
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
return 'Dog' + this.getName() + 'is barking';
};

var dog = new Dog('Aban');
alert(dog.getName() === 'Aban');
alert(dog.bark() === 'Dog Aban is barking');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `DogAbanis barking` !== `Dog Aban is barking` :)

Comment: Действительно, ведь надо пробелы.